# mysql date compare query gives wrong results

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have this table and the query I give returns wrong results, I am not sure where the problem is

1. the date comparisons

or

2. structure of the query

The query if not clear in the image is :

```
select * from transact where item_code='msft234' or item_code='hp550x' and transact_date>=STR_TO_DATE('06-07-2013','%d-%m-%Y') and transact_date<=STR_TO_DATE('12-07-2013','%d-%m-%Y')
```

[image]

Comment: please put all neccessary information here and do not just link to it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query employs a wrong syntax:

```
WHERE item_code='msft234' OR item_code='hp550x'
AND transact_date>=STR_TO_DATE('06-07-2013','%d-%m-%Y')
AND transact_date<=STR_TO_DATE('12-07-2013','%d-%m-%Y')
```

since AND priority is higher, it means that it will be satisfied if *either* you get hp550x in that date interval, *or* you get `msft234` *regardless of the date*.

You have to put the `OR`'ed item codes in parentheses: `(item_code='..' OR item_code='..' OR ..)`, or use `IN`: e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM transact
WHERE item_code IN ('msft234', 'hp550x')
AND transact_date BETWEEN
    STR_TO_DATE('06-07-2013','%d-%m-%Y')
    AND
    STR_TO_DATE('12-07-2013','%d-%m-%Y')
```

Also, depending on the type you select for the date fields, consider that for a date to be "less or equal than 12-07-2013", it has to be less or equal than 12-07-2013 at 00:00, i.e., almost the latest date that will match is 11-07-2013 at 23:59:59.

So "less or equal than 12-07" will actually **never select any row from 12-07-2013** unless it happens to have been inserted exactly at midnight.

If you insert rows by only specifying the *date*, then it will very probably work - the rows will be input at midnight and matched at midnight. But if (some) rows are entered with the full datetime, e.g. because they're type datetime and updated with `NOW()`, then they will *not* match.

Comment: thanks a lot..yes the transact_date is of DATE type and only the date is used

Comment: OK. It's just that, you see, I once made that mistake, and it took me a while to even realize it was there :-)

Answer (score 0):

put the item conditions between ()

```
(ítem_code = 'msft234' OR ítem_code = 'hp550x') AND transact_date>=STR_TO_DATE('06-07-2013','%d-%m-%Y') and transact_date<=STR_TO_DATE('12-07-2013','%d-%m-%Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

(ítem_code = 'msft234' OR ítem_code = 'hp550x') AND transact_date BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('06-07-2013','%d-%m-%Y') and STR_TO_DATE('12-07-2013','%d-%m-%Y')

Answer (score 0):

For security I will put with 2 ()

(ítem_code = 'msft234' OR ítem_code = 'hp550x') AND (transact_date BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('06-07-2013','%d-%m-%Y') and STR_TO_DATE('12-07-2013','%d-%m-%Y'))